# ggplot2: Add contour labels to kernel density plot produced with geom_density_2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add contour labels to a 2D kernel density plot made using [geom_density_2d](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html) in ggplot2?

```
library(ggplot2)

# load data
data("meuse")

# plot
ggplot(meuse, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_density_2d()
```

[image]

I tried extracting out the plotted data from the built ggplot object so I could pass it to [geom_text_contour](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/reference/geom_text_contour.html) from metR but the data it returns is a set of points that are used to plot the contour lines, not a grid of x/y coordinates geom_text_contour would need.

```
# extract denisty 2d
data <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
p + geom_path(data=data, 
              mapping=aes(color=nlevel, group=group), 
              color='red')
```

[image]

I want to make something like this (this example is from the [geom_text_contour documentation](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/reference/geom_text_contour.html)).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, `geom_text_contour` requires a `geom_contour` stat, which in turn requires a raster-like object, and not a collection of points as you have here.  However, there is the 'directlabels' library which can work with `geom_density_2d`.  This example is super ugly, but hopefully can get you started!  I changed the axis scale to make the contour values more manageable.

```
library(directlabels)

g1 <- ggplot(meuse %>% mutate(x=x/1000, y=y/1000), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_density_2d(aes(colour = ..level..))

direct.label(g1, list(top.pieces, colour = 'black'))
```

[image: contour plot with contours labeled]